# Composite-id hibernate complicated mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have a 3 tables A, B, C

```
Table A (
idA1 int unsigned not null,
idA2 int unsigned not null,
primary key(idA1, idA2)
)

Table B (
idB1 varchar(36) not null,
primary key(idB1)
)

Table C (
idC1 int unsigned not null,
idC2 varchar(36) not null,
idC3 int unsigned not null,
primary key(idC1, idC2, idC3),
foreign key(idC1, idC2) references A(idA1, idA2),
foreign key(idC3) references B(idB1)
)
```

I use conposite-id for keys table A but later faced with problem mapping table C
How to make hibernate mapping with next structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find good solution for my problem

[Solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/419780/NHibernate-mappings-for-Composite-Keys-with-associ)

Comment: It would be best if you could add the solution to your post in case the link goes down.